# AngularJS pass html content between directive tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know I can do this:

```
<my-directive attr="myAttr"></my-directive>
```

and then have the `attr` to be accessed via the `my-directive` side.

But I want to do something like this:

```
<my-directive attr="myAttr">
 <a href="">Some link that will apply with the my-directive directive too</a>
</my-directive>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Check the `ng-transclude` option.

Comment: I have checked and it works just perfect. Will I post the answer so others can know it too or that you will do this?

Comment: I think you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Using ng-transclude can solve the problem:

```
// html
<my-directive my-attr="Hello">
 <a href="#">My link</a>
</my-directive>

// my-directive.js 

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
 return {
  transclude: true,
  template: "<h1>{{myAttr}: <ng-transclude></ng-transclude></h1>", // <h1>Hello: <a href...>...</a></h1>
  scope: {
   myAttr: "@"
  },
  link: ($scope, element, attrs) => {

    console.log($scope.myAttr); // Hello

  }
 }
});
```

[Read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)